# Searching for Doctrine EventManager and Symfony EventDispatcher in one class

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I'm using some Doctrine ORM and some parts of Symfony. Doctrine has its own `Doctrine\Common\EventManager` class and Symfony uses its component `Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher`. I'd like to use just one manager/dispatcher service for handling events. There is no conflict between `Doctrine\Common\EventManager` and `Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcherInterface` so it should be possible to implement a class that would extend the EventManager from doctrine and implement the EventDispatcherInterface from Symfony. Is there such a package? Or is it a bad idea for some reason?

Comment: what is your objective ?

Comment: I'd like to eliminate the need of using two different services with similar purpose.

Comment: It is an interesting idea.  Doubt if it has been done before,  Currently, Symfony provides some support to making it easy to use Doctrine but does not actually depend on or require Doctrine.  Your proposed class would basically just have duplicate methods.  If there was a common psr event interface thn it might make some sense.  But as it is, I don't see much value.

Comment: I've never come across a case where I would need to do this.  Standard event dispatching in Symfony can come from services where you can import Doctrine as needed, and then Doctrine has its own events that you can listen on or subscribe to as well, where you could inject other services as necessary.